# Error 403 Forbidden when connect to Microsoft Defender API using Filebeat

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, filebeat

I am trying to connect to Microsoft Defender API using Elastic Filebeat. I followed the instructions here  register a new application with granted permission.

[Create app for Microsoft Defender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBM3d.png)

However, when trying to call the api, i encountered this message:

> Error while processing http request: failed to execute http client.Do:
> server responded with status code 403:
> {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"The application does not have
> any of the required application permissions (Alert.ReadWrite.All,
> Alert.Read.All, Incident.ReadWrite.All, Incident.Read.All) to access
> the resource.","target":}} {"input_source":
> "https://api.security.microsoft.com/api/incidents", "input_url":
> "https://api.security.microsoft.com/api/incidents"}

Can anyone assist me on this ?

EDIT: Added JWT token screenshot for reference if needed

[JWT decoded screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMAwd.png)

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Is there an update?

Answer (score 0):

Your token lacks permissions, you need to use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain the token:

[image]

Parse the token：

[image]